# Ext group of bundles on moduli space of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

Let $\mathcal{M}_{g}$ be the moduli space of curves of genus $g$. Let's suppose $g \geq 2$. Let $T$ be the tangent bundle of $\mathcal{M}_{g}$. Is the Ext group $\text{Ext}^1(\bigwedge^2T, T)$ trivial? If not, can we say anything about it?

Comment: You should ask this on mathoverflow